# How to sleep between awaiting pythonasyncio tasks to avoid rate limits

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I have a script to subscribe to websockets of over 1000 instruments on Deribit's API and feed the results to a queue and runs in a separate thread, however after a certain amount of websockets are opened within 1 second, I get rate limited. My solution is to open a websocket and then sleep for 100ms before awaiting the next websocket task, however I cannot figure out how to do this with asyncio. Here is the websocket code:

```
class Deribit:
    def __init__(self, contract, currency, q):
        self.baseUrl = "wss://www.deribit.com/ws/api/v2"
        self.contract = contract
        self.currency = currency
        self.q = q

    async def tickerSubscribe(self):
        msg = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "public/subscribe",
            "params": {"channels": [f"ticker.{self.contract}.raw"]},
        }
        async with websockets.connect(self.baseUrl) as websocket:
            await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
            while websocket.open:
                if flag == 'stop':
                    await websocket.close()
                    return
                else:        
                    response = await websocket.recv()
                    response = json.loads(response)
                    response['type'] = 'tickerSubscribe'
                    self.q.put(response)
            if not websocket.open:
                print('tickerSubscribe Closed')
                await self.tickerSubscribe()
    async def flowSubscribe(self):
        msg = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "public/subscribe",
            "params": {"channels": [f"trades.option.{self.currency}.raw"]},
        }
        async with websockets.connect(self.baseUrl) as websocket:
            await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
            while websocket.open:
                if flag == 'stop':
                    await websocket.close()
                    return
                else:        
                    response = await websocket.recv()
                    response = json.loads(response)
                    response['type'] = 'flowSubscribe'
                    self.q.put(response)
            if not websocket.open:
                print('flowSubscribe closed')
                await self.flowSubscribe()
```

Then here is the code to await the tasks:

```
async def main():
    tasks = []
    q = queue.Queue()
    coins = []
    print('Getting instruments..')
    while True:
        btc_instruments = Deribit('BTC', 'BTC', '').getInstruments('false')
        if btc_instruments != None:
            eth_instruments = Deribit('ETH', 'ETH', '').getInstruments('false')
            break
    print('Adding instruments to list..')
    for instrument in range(len(btc_instruments['result'])):
        orderbooks[btc_instruments['result'][instrument]['instrument_name']] = []
        coins.append(btc_instruments['result'][instrument]['instrument_name'])
    for instrument in range(len(eth_instruments['result'])):
        orderbooks[eth_instruments['result'][instrument]['instrument_name']] = []
        coins.append(eth_instruments['result'][instrument]['instrument_name'])
    for coin in range(len(coins)):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(Deribit(coins[coin], '', q).tickerSubscribe()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(Deribit('', 'BTC', q).flowSubscribe()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(Deribit('', 'ETH', q).flowSubscribe()))
    print(f'Length of Tasks list : {len(tasks)}')
    print('Subscribing to instruments..')
    for t in range(len(tasks)):
        await tasks[t]
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in  run_until_complete
     return future.result()
File "ws_correct_trades.py", line 199, in main
    await tasks[t]
File "ws_correct_trades.py", line 133, in tickerSubscribe
    async with websockets.connect(self.baseUrl) as websocket:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/client.py", line 517, in __aenter__
    return await self
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/client.py", line  535, in __await_impl__
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in    create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in    _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
ConnectionResetError
```

Comment: Please provide the Traceback - formatted as code.

Comment: I added the traceback, and I forgot to add this runs in a separate thread and that is included in the traceback

Comment: `tasks.append(...`  is `tasks` a list? - I don't see it defined anywhere. The `Deribit` methods used in `main` do not appear in the class; `main` never calls `tickerSubscribe` - it is hard to divine the flow and where the wait should be.  What are possible causes of a `ConnectionResetError`?

Comment: I apologize as I pasted the wrong portion. I've made the changes to it. Tasks is a list of asyncio.create_tasks() with each one having a Deribit.tickerSubscribe websocket with an instrument. After the for loop for the tickerSubscribe task appends, two additional appends are made for two websocket tasks. The code is correct now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...open a websocket and then sleep for 100ms before awaiting the next websocket task...

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines), there are three ways to **start** a coroutine. One is with `asyncio.create_task`. In your process, the loops that create the tasks are starting them immediately with no delay.  Here is a, hopefully analogous, mre - adapted directly from the example in the docs.

```
import asyncio, time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    # await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f"{time.perf_counter():1.5f} {what:>7}")

async def main():
    tasks = []
    print(f"start creating tasks {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
    for i in range(5):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(say_after(.1, f'task-{i}'),name=f'task-{i}'))

    print(f"sleeping 3 before awaiting tasks {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    for task in tasks:
        print(f"awaiting {task.get_name()} | {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
        await task
 
 
asyncio.run(main())
```

---

```
start creating tasks 0.79750
sleeping 3 before awaiting tasks 0.79803
0.79858  task-0
0.79891  task-1
0.79926  task-2
0.80382  task-3
0.80421  task-4
awaiting task-0 | 3.80519
awaiting task-1 | 3.80611
awaiting task-2 | 3.80744
awaiting task-3 | 3.80816
awaiting task-4 | 3.81093
```

You can see that the tasks are starting immediately when they are created - not when they are awaited.

---

Even if you add a delay **in** the couroutine, it doesn't accomplish what you want.

```
async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f"{time.perf_counter():1.5f} {what:>7}")

>>>
start creating tasks 0.89468
sleeping 3 before awaiting tasks 0.89484
1.00323  task-0
1.00376  task-1
1.00431  task-4
1.00467  task-3
1.00508  task-2
awaiting task-0 | 3.90330
awaiting task-1 | 3.90421
awaiting task-2 | 3.90542
awaiting task-3 | 3.90617
awaiting task-4 | 3.91162
```

Each one *processes* 100 mS after it is started but no delay between them.

---

Adding the delay to the loop should do what you want - create each task 100 mS apart.

```
async def say_after(delay, what):
    # await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f"{time.perf_counter():1.5f} {what:>7}")

async def main():
    tasks = []
    print(f"start creating tasks {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(say_after(.1, f'task-{i}'),name=f'task-{i}'))

    print(f"sleeping 3 before awaiting tasks {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    for task in tasks:
        print(f"awaiting {task.get_name()} | {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
        await task

>>>
start creating tasks 0.81102
0.91610  task-0
1.02837  task-1
1.13217  task-2
1.24762  task-3
sleeping 3 before awaiting tasks 1.35085
1.35127  task-4
awaiting task-0 | 4.36476
awaiting task-1 | 4.36564
awaiting task-2 | 4.36670
awaiting task-3 | 4.36752
awaiting task-4 | 4.37601
```

---

Or maybe you could submit in batches waiting between each batch.

```
async def main():
    tasks = []
    print(f"start creating tasks {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
    flag = 0
    n_per_second = 3
    while flag < 3:    # limit the number of batches for the example.
        print(f'batch:{flag}')
        for i in range(n_per_second):
            name = f'task-{(flag*10)+i}'
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(say_after(.1, name),name=name))

        await asyncio.sleep(1 / n_per_second)
        flag += 1
    print(f"sleeping 3 before awaiting tasks {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    for task in tasks:
        print(f"awaiting {task.get_name()} | {time.perf_counter():1.5f}")
        await task

asyncio.run(main()

>>>
start creating tasks 0.84680
batch:0        
0.84742  task-0
0.84749  task-1
0.84755  task-2
batch:1
1.19304 task-10
1.19334 task-11
1.19372 task-12
batch:2
1.54109 task-20
1.54149 task-21
1.54171 task-22
sleeping 3 before awaiting tasks 1.88965
awaiting task-0 | 4.90472
awaiting task-1 | 4.90519
awaiting task-2 | 4.90568
awaiting task-10 | 4.90766
awaiting task-11 | 4.90802
awaiting task-12 | 4.90836
awaiting task-20 | 4.91029
awaiting task-21 | 4.91057
awaiting task-22 | 4.91096
```